# How to maximize profit with a system that has 80% accuracy.

Tags: probability

So I have created a betting system that shows promising results. I took a small size of sample data of 20 matches & got 16 right. The odds of the bet will always be 1.83 or 5/6.
Assuming i start with a bankroll of 1000 how can i make the most of it

Comment: Do you ou mean $0.83$ instead of $1.83$ ?

Comment: No sir. That's how the bookmakers present there odds so essentially if i bet 100 units my profit is 83 units.

Comment: depends on the objective function you want to maximize. E.g., take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_criterion

Comment: BGM that was very helpful